# SQL Server trigger to drop another database

Tags: sql, triggers, sql-server-2012

I'm looking to drop a database using a trigger. The reason for this is that I have a table that holds client details, when a client is created a database is created for the client and all their data is held on their database. Thus deleting a client leaves an orphaned database. The client ID field (guid) is the database name. Any help would much be appreciated.

So far this is what I have tried:

```
CREATE TRIGGER DeletedClientDB
ON systemclients
FOR DELETE
AS
    DECLARE @db VARCHAR(50);

    SET @db = (SELECT deleted.SystemClientID FROM deleted)

    DROP DATABASE @db
GO
```

But can't get the syntax correct.

Comment: What did you try already?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Please use the appropriate tag, probably you will have a faster answer.

Comment: I wouldn't do that inside a trigger - a trigger should be very small, fast, nimble. Don't do heavy processing (like deleting an entire database!) inside a trigger!! Instead: in the trigger, write a *reminder* into a "databases-to-be-deleted" table, and then have a separate job in SQL Server that periodically checks that table and drops any databases mentioned in there.

Comment: Or send it to a service broker queue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**update**

After reading [Martin Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/73226/martin-smith)'s comments I've decided it's better to change my answer completely. I've kept the previous answer striked out so that the comments will not lose context.

Combining [marc_s](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13302/marc-s) comment and my own, I suggest simply to insert the deleted ids into a different table and have a scheduled job read the data from there and delete the databases.

<strike>Try this:</strike>

```
CREATE TRIGGER DeletedClientDB

ON systemclients

FOR DELETE
AS

DECLARE @dropdb VARCHAR(150);

Select @dropdb = 'drop database ' + deleted.SystemClientID FROM deleted)


Exec(@dropdb)

GO
```

Note you will need drop db permissions for the user that deletes the record in the clients table.

Comment: Delete can affect multiple rows.

Comment: Getting an error: "DROP DATABASE statement cannot be used inside a user transaction"

Comment: First, Martin of course is correct. Second, If your trigger is inside a transaction (as the error message suggests), then you simply can't use the trigger to drop the database. There are other things that can be done, like inserting the deleted client ids to a different table and have a scheduled job drop the databases and clean the table. This is just the first thing that pops into my mind, there might be better ways to handle this.

Comment: Triggers are always inside a transaction so this approach can never work.

Comment: Well actually it could work by comitting the parent transaction first inside the trigger but that would not be a correct solution.